# How can I run my Django app with gunicorn and daphna on heroku?

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, channel

I try to make a chat. There are some functions that work with "original" Django (def index(request) and so on) but also there are functions, where I need to use websockets. I installed channels to make a websocket interface. So, I have two systems: gunicorn interconnects with HTTP(S) and daphna interconnets with WS(S) interface. 
On my local machine I set up all files (asgi.py, consumers.py, routing.py and settings.py) and I type: python manage.py runserver - everything works. But when I deploy it to heroku, I get a lot of errors.

I tried everything, but didn't find the solution. Ask for your help.

Here are my files:

**chat/Procfile**

```
web: daphne Chat.asgi:channel_layer --port $PORT
web2: gunicorn Chat.wsgi
```

**chat/chat/asgi.py**

```
import os
import channels.asgi

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Chat.settings')
channel_layer = channels.asgi.get_channel_layer()
```

**chat/chat/routing.py**

```
from channels.routing import route

channel_routing = {
    'websocket.connect': 'user_chating.consumers.ws_connect',
    'websocket.receive': 'user_chating.consumers.ws_message',
    'websocket.disconnect': 'user_chating.consumers.ws_disconnect',
    #'send_email': 'user_chating.consumers.send_email_consumer'
}
```

**chat/chat/settings.py**

```
...

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'user_chating',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'channels',
]

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'asgiref.inmemory.ChannelLayer',
        'ROUTING': 'Chat.routing.channel_routing',
    },
}
ASGI_APPLICATION = "Chat.routing.application"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Chat.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR, 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Chat.wsgi.application'

...
```

**chat/chat/wsgi.py**

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Chat.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**chat/user_chatting/consumers.py**

```
import json
import time

from django.core.mail import send_mail
from channels.channel import Group


def ws_connect(message):
    Group('chat').add(message.reply_channel)
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})

def ws_message(message):
    Group('chat').send({'text': json.dumps({'message': message.content['text'],
                                            'sender': message.reply_channel.name})})

def ws_disconnect(message):
    Group('chat').discard(message.reply_channel)
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: What are the actual errors you are getting?